# Cannot resolve method findViewById(); while adding admob

Tags: java, android, admob

I learnt to integrate Admob banner ads, In main activity i wrote this code:

```
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And i also wanted the ads in another activity, So i copy pasted it. But i get a error as:

> error: cannot find symbol
>           AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById();

Cannot resolve method

> symbol:   method findViewById()

[Error-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UZeX.png)
I copy pasted this code in many other class files but it shows the same error.And it only works in MainActivity.java

i want to add ads under the textView.[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL50k.png)

Comment: You are trying to find view by id in your objectInitiate method , that is wrong

Comment: Where can i paste this code?

Comment: can u tell , which type of ad you are trying to show ?  banner / native ?

Comment: You have to do findviewById for adView in your activity class , your doing in your adapter class , that is wrong

Comment: i successfully added banner ads in mainactivity,now i want to add in other activity...banner ads

Comment: then you have to put , xml layout for adView in in your_activity.xml file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wXJBvn7n this is the code. please teach me in the answers coloumn

Comment: i have added adview in xml

Comment: it would be more clear , if u provide photo of output , so i can get more clear about where u want to load ad .

Comment: i've updates the answer @SaurabhMistry

Comment: please help me out with the information <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your CustomPagerAdapter

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, final int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, collection, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));


    AdView mAdView = (AdView) layout.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

Comment: 'qualifier' must be an expression!

Comment: you have done minor mistake , add below layout , you have added before it , so it is showing error

Comment: please reply after correction ? it is working or not ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/36JW2iqk this is the layout. the Textwidget (that allows user to type) cover s the whole screen. 
Like in the image it showed green screen which is now covered fully!

Comment: what mistake did i make? please tell me @Saurabh Mistry

Answer (score 1):

Add Adview to your `activity_layout.xml`

[image]

Add this Code in your Activity `onCreate` method.

[image]

Comment: I've already tried this, but it ain't working!  findViewById shows error

Comment: Yes but you have to add this your activity class , not in CustomPagerAdapter class

Comment: You have provided only CustomPagerAdapter, that is used for setting up recyclerview , but not for showing ad , you have to provide code for your activity

Comment: which activity or fragment u are using for showing this chat layout ?

Comment: i dont have teamviewer

Comment: please provide code for activity or fragment , that in which u r showing this layout ?

Comment: CustomPagerAdapter

Comment: in custompageradapter it has a Text widget.

Comment: i want below it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Just copy and paste the additional 3 lines code into your file.


implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'


implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```